# How to use VB Printer object in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, printing

I'm trying to print to an Epson printer using VBA code without success. Using VB6, I have the following code which it works just fine:

```
Printer.Print "Hello"
Printer.EndDoc
```

My problem is that I don't see the Printer object in VBA (using MS Access Macros).
Do I have to include a specific reference? If yes, what it would be? such that I have VB6 runtime installed on the same machine.

Comment: Did you see: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?t=19180 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this from MS Access, but [KB154078](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154078) shows VBA code that can use the Win32 API to communicate directly with the print spooler and send raw data to a printer:

```
  Option Explicit

  Private Type DOCINFO
      pDocName As String
      pOutputFile As String
      pDatatype As String
  End Type

  Private Declare Function ClosePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal _
     hPrinter As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function EndDocPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal _
     hPrinter As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function EndPagePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal _
     hPrinter As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function OpenPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias _
     "OpenPrinterA" (ByVal pPrinterName As String, phPrinter As Long, _
      ByVal pDefault As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function StartDocPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias _
     "StartDocPrinterA" (ByVal hPrinter As Long, ByVal Level As Long, _
     pDocInfo As DOCINFO) As Long
  Private Declare Function StartPagePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal _
     hPrinter As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function WritePrinter Lib "winspool.drv" (ByVal _
     hPrinter As Long, pBuf As Any, ByVal cdBuf As Long,  _
     pcWritten As Long) As Long

  Private Sub Command1_Click()
      Dim lhPrinter As Long
      Dim lReturn As Long
      Dim lpcWritten As Long
      Dim lDoc As Long
      Dim sWrittenData As String
      Dim MyDocInfo As DOCINFO
      lReturn = OpenPrinter(Printer.DeviceName, lhPrinter, 0)
      If lReturn = 0 Then
          MsgBox "The Printer Name you typed wasn't recognized."
          Exit Sub
      End If
      MyDocInfo.pDocName = "AAAAAA"
      MyDocInfo.pOutputFile = vbNullString
      MyDocInfo.pDatatype = vbNullString
      lDoc = StartDocPrinter(lhPrinter, 1, MyDocInfo)
      Call StartPagePrinter(lhPrinter)
      sWrittenData = "How's that for Magic !!!!" & vbFormFeed
      lReturn = WritePrinter(lhPrinter, ByVal sWrittenData, _
         Len(sWrittenData), lpcWritten)
      lReturn = EndPagePrinter(lhPrinter)
      lReturn = EndDocPrinter(lhPrinter)
      lReturn = ClosePrinter(lhPrinter)
  End Sub
```

Another example is given in [KB175083](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175083).

Comment: The Win32 API doesn't work for me since I need to format the text to be printed, e.g changing the font weight, etc. I finally adopted a workaround solution:I created a VB6 ActiveX DLL and I'm using it in my VBA script. But the problem is that I need to install VB6 runtime on my clients machines.

Comment: @rsleiman, you can use the win32 api to change the font and stuff too, look up `SelectObject` and `CreateFont`.